# msvcr71.dll is missing

Tags: windows-7, windows, libraries, dll

msvcr71.dll is missing on Windows 7 and I can't register my dll throw `regsvr32`

I just can't understand why it can happen
Does this dll come with OS, or I can install C++ runtime libraries, or .NET framework to present this file in Windows?

**The question is**: what (C++ runtime/NET framewor/...) have I to download to present this file in Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`msvcr71.dll` is *Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library* [for Visual C++ .NET 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922). It comes as part of [.NET Framework 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26).